# Tags around partitions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, we have tags

- [partition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition),
- [partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions) and
- [partition-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition-problem).

The tags seem to be used a little arbitrarily, and the former two should probably be synonyms. There are no descriptions helping users along.

What should we do with theses?

Answer (score 4):

I think we mostly have to differentiate between partitions of integers and sets. The latter appears in many contexts in CS but we have other tags to clarify the context. Therefore, I suggest the following.

- Create tag [integer-partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integer-partitions).

  > Partitions of an integer n are different ways of writing n as sum of smaller integers.
- [partitions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partitions) ← [partition](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition)

  > A partition or partitioning of a set A is a collection of disjoint sets whose union yields A.
- Remove [partition-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partition-problem).

  Questions can be tagged with one of the above tags plus [discrete-mathematics](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrete-mathematics), [data-structures](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-structures), [complexity-theory](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complexity-theory), [decision-problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decision-problem), or [optimization](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optimization) to disambiguate.